# How to construct this matrix in Mathematica

Tags: functions, matrix

I create a symbolic matrix using the following:

```
mat = ToExpression[Table[StringJoin[{"s", ToString[i], ToString[j]}], {i, 1, d}, {j, 1, d}]]
```

for arbitrary $d$. Notice that for $d=2$, this gives

$$\begin{pmatrix} s11 & s12 \\ s21 &s22\end{pmatrix}.$$

I do this since an analytic expression is important. However, I would like to get numerics. How can I update the above define for `mat` to get a function of the form:

```
matNEW[s11_, s12_, s21_, s22_]
```

such that I can evaluate the matrix later in the script for specific values of the parameters.

Comment: Start by using indexed variables instead of constructed expressions, such as `s[1, 2]` etc. Then making your array is simple: `mat[d_Integer] := Array[s, {d, d}]`. Later on, use replacements on your `mat`: `mat[2] /. {s[1, 1] -> 2, ...}` perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [`Indexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) with [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html) to create a matrix that can be switched between symbolic and numeric content.

To input the script capital R symbol enter: <kbd>Esc</kbd> `scR` <kbd>Esc</kbd> . See more at [Notational Alphabet Characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NotationalAlphabetCharacters.html).

```
indexedArray[m_Symbol, dims_?(VectorQ[#, # ∈ PositiveIntegers &] &)] :=
 Array[Indexed[m, {##}] &, dims]
```

`indexedArray` builds a symbolic matrix on the **unassigned** symbol provided.

```
ℛ = indexedArray[r, {3, 2}];
MatrixForm@ℛ
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### For symbolic calculations:

```
Transpose@ℛ // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 = indexedArray[c, {2, 3}];
.ℛ // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### For numeric calculations:

We need to assign values to `r` not `ℛ`.

```
r = Partition[Range@6, 2];
MatrixForm@ℛ
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{Range@3}.ℛ // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
.ℛ // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

#### To return to symbolic calculations

Clear the `Indexed` variable to return to symbolic calculations.

```
r =.
ℛ // MatrixForm
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks for the script formatting.  I did not realise that the Mma.SE Editor Tools worked on script symbols.  Is this from a recent update?

Comment: You’re right, the editor doesn’t. I used http://steampiano.net/msc/ , which got the script R, and finally I copy-pasted the script C from a wiki page :-)

Comment: @MarcoB No, it does do it now. I tried it before posting the comment.  It didn't when I first used it a long time ago but it does do scripts now.

Comment: Well that’s interesting! You’re right, it worked. I wonder what I did wrong the first time. Even better then!

Comment: @Edmund, great answer. Couple of questions. 1. How does `indexedArray` set the indices of `r` as subscripts? 2. Also, how does `r = Partition[Range@6, 2];` assign values to the values of `r`? Can we instead set the values as a function of their indices? i.e. `rjk = f[j,k]` for some defined function `f`.

Comment: @Sid 1. `Indexed` `OutputForm` formats it with subscripts. 2.Yes, you can assign values as a function of the indices.  One example would be `r = Array[f[##]&, {3,2}]`.